# Driving a solenoid with a relay

Tags: solenoid

I'm trying to run a backup pump that will be actuated by a no flow condition from the primary pump. Everything is 12V DC. The flow switch can only handle 0.4A at 12V DC. The issue I'm running into is finding a solenoid that can be actuated with less than 0.4A that is affordable and reliable. I've only found a traditional mechanical solenoid which is actuated by 0.7A.

I've been told that the flow switch can activate a relay which in turn activates a solenoid.  How would I design a circuit like this?

Comment: Sadly, the first part looks like a 'shopping question' - see [help] for advice on writing good questions. You might want to reword it a bit. How might you specify 'affordable' and 'reliable'? Do you know about solid-state relays, or are you saying they are no good either?

Comment: A solenoid and a relay are both effectively electromagnets. The technique using transistors to drive a relay can also be used to drive a solenoid. Therefore, you shouldn't need *both* a relay and a solenoid.

Comment: @jyelton then explain every car system ever. Obviously they are both electromagnets, but when one requires significantly more power than the other, and the trigger can only power the weaker one... Op understands this but wants to check.

Comment: @Passerby Not saying you *never* combine relay and solenoid, but for 0.4 to 0.7A, I don't see why it's needed here.

Comment: @jyelton 0.4 to 0.7 is 175% of the rated  capacity of the flow switch. thats why its needed.

Comment: What does the solenoid actually do with respect to the two pumps? Normally, you just connect redundant pumps in parallel, with check valves on their output sides. Why is a solenoid needed at all?

Comment: @DaveTweed I assume he's talking about a solenoid valve.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Maybe, but that still doesn't explain why it's needed in this situation.

Comment: @DaveTweed AFAIUI, he's got a mechanical switch that is rated 0.4A maximum and a solenoid valve that draws almost twice as much, so he needs a MOSFET, a BJT, a relay or something.. and a relay is probably easiest.

Comment: @DaveTweed I could run both pumps in parallel like you said but it isn't very energy efficient and they both might wear out at the same time leaving me with no pumps.  The flow switch can only handle 0.4A so it will be used to actuate a relay and the solenoid actuates on 0.7A so it will be actuated by the relay and it will then provide power to a second pump if now flow is detected from the first pump.

Comment: So, by "solenoid", you're referring to the contactor that controls the second pump? I wasn't suggesting that you run both pumps at the same time; I was just saying that they were plumbed in parallel.

Comment: Yes,  they are plumbed and wired in parallel (I think it's possible to fail but still draw power and I don't want to blow a fuse by powering them both even though one isn't working or have one short and pop the fuse and have no power for the second.) The solenoid is just to complete the circuit of the second pump and since the solenoid draws too much for the switch a relay completes the circuit of the solenoid.  The switch is a flow switch after the first pump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you would need is a 12V coil relay rated for sufficient contact current (for example, 10A relays are common and inexpensive). It might also be advisable to connect a diode (eg. 1N4004) across the relay coil (and another across the solenoid coil) to reduce sparking in the flow switch (and relay contacts).

Panasonic JS-1A relays and similar are one choice for the relay.